# CodeIgniter 3 on 000webhost 404 not found

Tags: php, .htaccess, codeigniter, hosting, web-hosting

please guide me on how to load the website in the CodeIgniter 3 framework in 000webhost, I fixed also the base_url and database

[image]
[image]

.htaccess

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ ../index.php/$1 [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ ../index.php/$1 [L]
```

The File location of htaccess is inside the folder of the web application
public_html/web_application/.htaccess

Comment: What URL are you going to and where is your htaccess file located?

Comment: 000webhost is a very instable hosting provider, please try another one

Comment: @AdamP. is there any free Webhosting do you know? I would like to try it

Comment: Are you sure you need web hosting? Is localhost not enough for you?

Comment: it is part of the college requirements in the university to present as a demo,